# Providing in-form help in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm a non-developer building a simple Access 2003 database for an NGO that works in developing countries. I would like to provide in-app help (what certain fields mean, for example) in a number of forms and on the switchboard. I'm not sure about the best way to do this - not just on a technical standpoint but to increase user-friendliness. The users are usually using MS Access for the very fist time, and have only basic computer use knowledge.

I don't want to cram the forms with help text, so I'm thinking of adding little question mark buttons that pop up a separate form with just help text. Is that wise?

I've also noticed a Help Context ID property, but it looks complicated (I'm looking for something as simple as possible to implement, so that the help text can be edited as easily as possible by others in the future). I think this is where I'd start if this were the way to go: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=209843

This may need to be translated, etc, so again, the simpler the better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built such a system using tables and forms in the FE.  You can get an idea by reviewing some of the screen shots at http://www.granitefleet.com/ScreenShots/index.htm   I only created general help describing processes where something on a setup form can affect this form.  So the user will know where to ge to change something around.

Comment: I like your use of question mark buttons for various fields in a form. I was thinking one help button per form but this is better - doesn't require each popup to have so much information in it. It means creating more forms but it seems like a tradeoff worth making.

Comment: How do you mean more forms? All the help is in a table. I just open the help form to a different record. Also the same help button is called from different places if they are related. For example there is service interval fields at the global, equipment roup and unit level so the help button opens the same record in each form

Comment: I also have a form which shows all the help pages so they can browse each one at their leisure in addition to encountering them at they go along.

BTW thanks for asking.  One of these days I'm going to put all my thoughts together on this topic and write a page on my website.

Comment: Wow, now it seems obvious, but it hadn't occurred to me to store all the help text in one table... It's genius! Will save me lots of time and allow it to scale, get translated, etc much better. Thanks so much.

Comment: However ...  You can't bold headings, insert graphics or hyperlinks, and other formatting things like that.  OTOH that can be good enough.

Comment: Also if you're depending on translaters you may want to capture the datetime of each time you've edited your native language of the help text.  So the translating team know that you've changed the page.   You may also want to keep versions of the records kicking around too so the translaters can see what's changed.   Finally you may even want to put that table in it's own MDB so it is easier for the translaters to update.   OTOH you might want to just import the complete table.

Comment: Also feel free to download the system at the Granite Fleet Manager so you can get a feel for how I've done things.  Although it's really only one table and about three forms.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't built your forms yet, put that information in the table design, using each field's Description. That will propagate through your forms, and will be displayed on the Status Bar whenever a user click in that field.

If your forms are already done, use the [Status Bar Text] and/or the [ControlTip Text] property of your controls.

Just train your users or write once that they should read the Status bar if they need more explanation.

KISS (keep it simple and simple)

Comment: Thanks iDevlop, that's a great suggestion. The forms are already done, and I really like Tony Toews suggestion (below) which I'm going to go with. I'll complement that with ControlTip text however, as you suggest.

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Great question. I think the real solution to reducing the amount of work that you need to do is to work really hard on having a simple, clean UI. In the real world there are very few people who have the patience or inclination to read the manual or search the contextual help even in the face of being stuck.

I know this is slightly off topic from the question but if you look at this website for example it keeps the number of things you can do on anyone 'screen' down to the minimum and everything has a tool tip (ControlTip Text in msaccess). Even if site this was in Japanese, I thin i could navigate around it fairly easily and that is because of its simplicity. (I couldn't answer any questions though :P)

Jakob Neilsen has a great site on [usability](http://www.useit.com/)

Comment: Thanks John, that's great advice. I'm doing my best to keep the interface uncluttered and focused, but there are certain 'data' questions users may have that I think still need help text. (For example, when does a user enter something as a 'field activity' rather than an 'event'.) But the tool-tips idea is a good one - doesn't require opening a new form and is somewhat more discoverable. (Especially as users get in the habit of checking for them.)

Answer (score -1):

> " I think the real solution to reducing the amount of work that you need to do is to work really hard on having a simple, clean UI. In the
>   real world there are very few people who have the patience or
>   inclination to read the man*emphasized text*ual or search the
>   contextual help even in the face of being stuck.*

Regarding this, it really depends on the application. It is overly simplistic to assume that every application can have all the information it needs to be operated just by having a simple clean UI, especially if in the name of being simple, there are alot of useful features that are not included. In certain complex applications, people will simply need to have patience and read the information available or they will waste a lot of time guessing. It is better to have have information at the press of a button than have them asking for it once they figured out that they are wasting time figuring it out with no help. I agree that many apps are way more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I suggest this should be added as a comment to Jack Nolan's answer.  It is not an answer on its own.